# Really weird JQuery scrollTop issue break all other jquery functions

Tags: jquery, scrolltop

I'm trying to do a simple jquery smooth scroll, but when I put the code:

```
$("a.fashion").click(function(){
    $("html,body").animate({scrollTop:0}, "slow");
});
```

All my other jquery code stops working. 
Only when I add the line:

```
$("html,body").animate({scrollTop:0}, "slow");
```

I can add anything else in that function and it will work but not that line. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Put scrollTop in quotes maybe... "scrollTop"

Comment: I would change "body, html" to ' window' see if that helps. I can see binding two elements to an .on(' scroll') function but not to a scroll animation.

Answer (score 0):

May be this will help you.Change the line as follow

```
$("a.fashion").click(function(){
 $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: $(document).height()}, 'slow'); 
return false;
});
```

or just follow this link [Smooth scrolling](http://designwoop.com/2011/01/using-jquery-to-create-smooth-page-scrolling/)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer all. I just figured out the problem. It seemed to have been linked to weird spacing in the function block. I pasted it inline and it worked then made sure when I put it on the next line it was only one tab space (instead of a tabspace and a piece). Weird. Didn't think whitespace mattered... O_o

Comment: Whitespace doesn't matter if it's not inside a string/regex and if it doesn't force ASI. Maybe there was something else there.

Comment: Whitespace does not matter. However, when cutting & pasting code found elsewhere, like on a webpage, you will sometimes pick up invisible characters hidden within the whitespace that will break the code.  Go ahead, type the whitespace back in, you'll see it works fine.